# Zurb Foundation 5 tooltip in wrong location

Tags: javascript, css, tooltip, zurb-foundation

Copy/pasted the example from zurb and I have the css and js loaded. When I hover over the words, the tolltip operates normally until it finishes it's transition and then it pins itself to the bottom of the screen. Any ideas what's going on?

I uploaded the dev site here: http://westend.rizenweb.com/neighborhood/. Hover over the words 'extended information' to see what's happening. Thanks!

Comment: did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed this,
Initialize Foundation
After you have included the Foundation Javascript, just add a simple call to initialize all plugins on your page.

We recommend that you initialize Foundation at the end of the page .

HTML

```
  <script>
   $(document).foundation();
  </script>
```